# Visual Studio 2017 cannot create bookmarks in python files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Can you place bookmarks in a python program with Visual Studio 2017? I have tried using the 'Toggle bookmark on this line' button, but it does nothing. Is the problem related to the fact that Python uses white space to separate code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it works using <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> (Toggling Bookmark) when sitting in a line of my python file.

Jumping to it via <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> works as well. (Vanilla VS Community Edition 2017).

The menu items in Edit/Bookmarks/... work as well.

After I added the TextEditor Menu Bar I was also able to put a bookmark via the button you mentioned.